# assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast

Tags: c

In the below code am getting an error while am assigning `len1` to array `a`
The error is

```
assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast
```

Please help me.

```
void main()
{
    int i=0;
    char a[7]={0x00,0xdc,0x01,0x04};
    char str[70] = "123456644454464644456456456564564544132131113132132";
    int len=0;
    char len1[50]={};
    len = strlen(str);
    printf("The Length is : %02x", len);
    printf("The Length is : %d", len);
    sprintf(len1,"0x%02x",len);
    printf("The Len1 value : %s", len1);

    a[4]=len1; // This line causes the error.

    for(i=0;i<=7;i++)
    {   
        printf("%05c",a[i]);
        //printf("%x",a[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `a[4]=len1` supposed to do ?

Comment: This `a[4]=len1` should be `strncpy(&a[4], len1, 2)` Assuming you're trying to copy the first 2 characters from len (the hex value) into location 5+6 of the array a.

Comment: Seriously, you need to read a book which explains basics of C programming.

Comment: @Asha Thanks Asha... For your Kind Information..... You Got Knowledge Over C Programming I hope....

Comment: This line `for(i=0;i<=7;i++)` will cause another error when you try `a[i]` later. It counts one step too far!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `a[4]` is a `char`, whereas `len1` is an array of chars!

When you declare

```
char a[7] = {...}
```

You're saying that you want a to be an array of chars and you're initializing the values at a to the values in `{...}`.

When you say `a[4]` you're saying go 4 along from where a is and use the value there, which is a `char`.
But `len1` is a `char pointer` so when you assign it to `a[4]` you get the warning!

Comment: +1 @Michael; -1 @Bogwonch: I like section 6 of the [c-faq](http://c-faq.com/) to illustrate the point that **arrays are not pointers**.

Comment: Fair enough!  I've gone and looked up the difference and you're right!

Comment: -1 revoked after the edit ... but "`len1` decays to a `char pointer`" :)

Answer (score 1):

What are the types of the (sub-)expressions in your statement?

```
a[4] = len1;
```

`len1` is an array of 50 chars (type `char[50]`) but in the expression above it decays to a pointer to its first element. That's a value of type `char*`.
`a[4]` is an object of type `char`.

You cannot assign a `char*` to an object of type `char`!

I think maybe you wanted

```
/* BEWARE BUFFER OVERFLOWS */
strcpy(a+4, len1); /* a+4 is of type `char*`, len1 decays to `char*` */
```